# Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) GWT Client Debugging error

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

I just tried to switch to the new Eclipse version (2020-09) with my GWT 2.9.0 application.
This produced the error :

[image: Eclipse error message]

I checked it with the default GWT Project Generator (ie. File - new - Project - GWT Application - GWT Web Application Project - sample code automatically generated). Same issue here. When
right clicking the Eclipse GWT Sample Project Name - Debug As - GWT Development Mode with Jetty.
After it compiled I right clicked the link http://127.0.0.1:8888/TestNeu.html and chose "Open with SDBG Chrom JS Debugger". Then error message appears.

Client breakpoints are not hit with the new Eclipse Version!?

Comment: I think the latest Eclipse requires Java 11. Think, the GWT plugin does not work with Java 11.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I cannot comment on the validity of your answer. Still I went back to the old 09-2019 version of eclipse - all worked well again.